# How do I make 'Y' Tax-Free in Shopping Cart Price Rule "Buy X, Get Y Free"?

Tags: magento-1.7, tax, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to create a rule whereby a customer buys 10 of one product and get's the 11th free.

This works a treat... However, Magento is calculating the tax based on 11 products instead of 10 (because the 11th should be 100% free).

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

E.g. I have a product that is £1.00. UK Tax on this would be 20% (20p), so if I buy 10 of these, the tax should be £2.00, but it is coming in at £2.20 even though Magento is showing a discount of £1.00.

*When I say fix, it might not be broken to some, but I couldn't think of a better word ;)
And I hope I've been clear enough... First post. Please ask if you need me to clarify.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've set up your rule, but when tax is applied can be configured:

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings > Apply Customer Tax
```

Comment: Schoolboy error, can't believe I forgot about this setting. My bad, thanks Cags!

Also, I would vote up but don't have enough rep yet